# Backbone.js Sending Variables with destroy/delete

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js

I'm new to backbone and I am trying to send a delete command. I'm using the post modification option but the delete only send the method. Example below:

```
    Backbone.emulateHTTP = true;
    Backbone.emulateJSON = true;
    ProductImageModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

            initialize : function() {
            },

            url : "/products/ajaximage",
        });
    //Later called using
    var image = new ProductImageModel({id: id});
    image.destroy();
```

The problem is, the id is never passed, and all that appears in the $_POST is this:

```
Array
(
    [_method] => DELETE
)
```

Is there a way to pass the id in the delete?

Comment: What version of Backbone.js are you using? (`console.log(Backbone.VERSION)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reviewing the annotated source, and looking at your code... You're overriding the `Model.url` method with a static property.  The `Backbone.Model.url` method looks like this:

```
url: function() {
    var base = getValue(this, 'urlRoot') || getValue(this.collection, 'url') || urlError();
    if (this.isNew()) return base;
    return base + (base.charAt(base.length - 1) == '/' ? '' : '/') + encodeURIComponent(this.id);
}
```

Which is generating your URL for you on the fly based on whether your model is new, or not.

What you should be doing, instead of defaulting your `Model.url` property to `'/products/ajaximage'` is defaulting the `Model.urlRoot` property to `'/products/ajaximage'`.  That should allow you to execute `Model.destroy()` and get the model's ID as part of the request url to the server, so you know which model you need to delete.

Comment: No, my request is only: /products/ajaximage

Comment: This worked in sending as part of the string: urlRoot : "/products/ajaximage",
  url : function() {
   var base = this.urlRoot || (this.collection && this.collection.url) || "/";
   if(this.isNew())
    return base;

   return base + "?id=" + encodeURIComponent(this.id);
  }

Comment: I was mistaken, revising my answer. ;o